# Zxing.Net ReadQRCode

Tags: vb.net

I am using the Zxing.Net library to generate QR codes.  I update each users QRcode on a daily basis, based on answers to a daily health survey.  If it is a new user, the QRCode is created for the first time on the web server.  If the file already exists, it just writes over it.

I have begun using the ReadQRCode() sub in a different process to read the QR code and display the data.  However, after doing so, I can no longer update the QR code as it is "being used by another process".  This only happens when I use the ReadQRCode() sub to read/decode the QR to a web page.  The only way I have been able to remove this "file lock" is by restarting the web server.

Generate the QRCode which is not the issue:

```
  Public Sub GenerateCode(name As String)
        Dim intLoc As Integer
        Dim strFileName As String

        intLoc = Strings.InStr(name, "_")
        strFileName = name.Substring(0, intLoc - 1)
        name = name.Trim()
        Dim writer = New BarcodeWriter()
        writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
        Dim result = writer.Write(name)
        Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("~/qrCodeImages/" & strFileName & ".jpg")
        Dim barcodeBitmap = New Bitmap(result)

        Using memory As New MemoryStream()
            Using fs As New FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
                barcodeBitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                Dim bytes As Byte() = memory.ToArray()
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
                fs.Close()
            End Using
            memory.Close()
        End Using
```

**Reading the qrcode image**:

```
Sub ReadQRCode()
        Dim reader = New BarcodeReader()
        Dim filename As String = Path.Combine(Request.MapPath("~/qrCodeImages/"), strFileName & ".jpg")
        ' Detect and decode the barcode inside the bitmap
        Dim result = reader.Decode(New Bitmap(filename))
        If result IsNot Nothing Then
            qrData.Visible = True
            qrData.Text = "QR Code: " + result.Text
        End If

    End Sub
```

[Error trying to update QRCode after it has been read by Sub ReadQRCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtmKP.jpg)

Comment: Show us the code. Always provide all the relevant information and the code you're using is always relevant.

Comment: You've probably used(/caused the use of) something like Image.FromFile and then not disposed the result which means a file lock lingers, but really my question is "if your image file is on a web server, why aren't you simply building HTML that contains a link to the url of the image file, and then the problem of requesting the image is handled directly by the web server, without your code's involvement" ?

Comment: Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added the code as well as an image of the error that is produced when trying to update the qrcode AFTER it has been read.  The error only occurs when the qrcode has been read by the Sub ReadQRCode()

Answer (score 0):

You have to dispose the bitmap instance which is created for the decoding process. It is a common problem that the Bitmap class holds the file in a locked state until it is disposed or collected by the GC. Try the following code snippet.

```
Sub ReadQRCode()
    Dim reader = New BarcodeReader()
    Dim filename As String = Path.Combine(Request.MapPath("~/qrCodeImages/"), strFileName & ".jpg")
    ' Detect and decode the barcode inside the bitmap
    Using bitmap As New Bitmap(filename)
        Dim result = reader.Decode(bitmap)
        If result IsNot Nothing Then
            qrData.Visible = True
            qrData.Text = "QR Code: " + result.Text
        End If
    End Using

End Sub
```

Perhaps you should add using blocks in the method GenerateCode, too.